# Not getting data in Laravel Where

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wanted to get data from the selected model, and for that first, I am plucking user ids and getting data in the array, then passing it to the Laravel `WhereIn` function, but it's returning no value.

```
if (!empty($min_height)) {
    $user_ids = PhysicalAttribute::where('height', $min_height)
        ->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
    
    if (count($user_ids) > 0) {
        $users = $users->WhereIn('id', $user_ids)->get();
    }
}
```

It's returning null.

[image]

Comment: Add `->get()` before `->pluck()`

Comment: U sure that `$user_ids` contains at least 1 value?
P.S. you have to use `whereIn` instead of `WhereIn`.
To ensure that builder generates the query you want, you can use `$query->dd()` or `dd($query->toSql())`

Comment: @SimonK , pluck works without using `get` method

Comment: Oh OK, thank you

Comment: What is `$users`?  What does `var_dump($user_ids)` look like?

Comment: And what is `$min_height`?